# Change android studio saving and excecuting path

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to change android studio file paths in order to make space in my internal ssd. How can I do that?

Comment: which file paths you mean?

Comment: @MiladBahmanabadi I mean every file of android studio, I want the whole program to be executed into my external ssd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For change SDK location:
  press `ctrl + alt + shift + s --> SDK Location --> Android SDK location`
- For change android studio projects:
  simply cut your projects and paste in your internal SSD
- For change AVD location (windows):

1. press `windows button`
2. type `edit the system environment variables`
3. click on `Environment Variables...`
4. click on `New button` for creating an environment variable with name `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` and value `your internal ssd location`
5. click `ok`
6. move `.android` folder to `your internal ssd location`